# How can we remove the elements ithat we don't want from the array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, multidimensional-array

I have an image of dimension as (1186, 1225, 3) (attached below). The blue region is not of my interest; the region showed up after when I cropped my area of interest from the parent imagery. The region is represented by the value of 255 for all the bands. How do I get rid of this region or how I can exclude it from further analysis. Any help is appreciated.

[image: picture of gras with blue borders]

Comment: seems as if you need to rotate your image by roughly 5.5° and them trim it - what did you try to fix it?

Comment: What is _further analysis_?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Even If I rotate, there still will be blue region since the area of interest is not a square. Can we assign the elements with the value of 255 to Nan? Does it help?

Comment: @DYZ I am trying to generate spectral indices and calculate hsv and lab color spaces. I thought that the array value for the blue region would interfere with the analysis (for example, thresholding)

Comment: If all blue pixels in the image are invalid, simply ignore all blue pixels.

Comment: If the arrays can't just be rotated, you can also mask it: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#rationale